# jQuery resets when C# method is run

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a "newsletter" widget, that can expand when the user presses a button. Inside the expanded container is an input box along with a "submit" button. My codebehind checks if the email is valid and then sends an mail if it is. If the email is invalid it puts an error message into a label.

The problem is that when I click my submit button the jQuery function resets and the container is no longer expanded.

```
$('.widget').click(function () {
    $('.widget').addClass('wdly');
    $('.widly').addClass('window');
});

$('.hide1').click(function () {
    $('.widget').removeClass('wdly');
    $('.widly').removeClass('window');
});
```

```html
<div class="widget">
    <span class="mail" style="margin-left: 3px">Newsmail</span>
</div>
<div class="widly">
    <span class="hide1"></span>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="form-control newsmail"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Label ID="emailRegEx" runat="server" Text="Label" style="position:absolute; margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 60px;" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-lg btn-success submit" OnClick="submit_Click1" />            
</div>
```

```csharp
protected void submit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(txtEmail.Text, @"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        // send email
    }
    else
    {
        emailRegEx.Visible = true;
        emailRegEx.Text = "Invalid E-mail format";
    }
}
```

I guess what i'm looking for is some kind of partial load, that makes the DOM remember the current settings of my widget, instead of rolling it back to the initial setting.

Comment: The issue is because clicking the button causes a reload of the page (as the data is round-tripped to the server), so the page is loaded again from it's starting state. If you want to avoid this you either need to store the state of the page (cookies, sessionStorage, localStorage etc.) or change the logic of the page to use AJAX instead. The latter is much more preferable, although could be an involved process when having one hand tied behind your back by WebForms.

Comment: You're posting to the server so the page reloads completely. If you want partial updates use an UpdatePanel or make your own ajax calls.

Comment: Well, i've never learned .NET MVC in my school. But i have vague experience with ajax. Do you know what i should look for in regards to this question - tutorials etc. ?

Comment: [Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) seems reasonable

Comment: I just briefly looked through it. If i understand it correctly, i leave ajax to take care of the postback, so that "ajax updates" instead of the entire page?

Comment: `postback` is the culprit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When click event called page is post back so jquery event not fire.You need to assign a partial postback handler in JavaScript.

```
function functionname() {
   // do something
}
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(functionname);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However im not sure what is going on here, and how i should invoke my script into this function?

Comment: Put your all code in one function. Call that function document.ready event and register as well as i describe with sys.webforms.pagerequest...

Comment: So there should not be any issue. Put your script at the end of page.